# How to know the shell started with :terminal?

Tags: vimscript, terminal

After `:terminal` runs, is there a way within Vim script to determine the type of shell that started with creation of the terminal ?  *within Vimscript, NOT via OS commands* such as `ps`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help :terminal`,

```
        If [command] is not given the 'shell' option is used.
```

So you can retrieve the shell executable which will be run with `&shell`.

If you want to get the command line used to start the terminal, irrespective of `'shell'`, just use the buffer name, e.g.,

```
let l:terms = term_list()
let l:bufname = empty(l:terms) ? '' : bufname(l:terms[-1])
let l:shell = substitute(l:bufname, '^!', '', 'g')
```

Comment: Thanks Mass.  I asked the question b/c the quoted section from :help does not account for the scenario when [command] specs a shell, and your 2nd approach is what I was looking for.